# Android SQLite i can't find the database created on a rooted real device

Tags: android, database, sqlite, root

i have a database which is created with my application on a real device: IconiaTab A500
I have rooted the tablet yesterday.

The problem is: i can't find this database.
I have the ES FileExplorer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android stores all application databases in the following location:
/data/data/**name.of.your.package**/databases/**database_name.db**

You need root to access this path. Also make sure that the application you are using is capable of browsing system directories and that you have this option enabled in the settings.

Comment: Problem resolved, i used ES FileExploer which has no root privileges.
With RootExplorer or something like this, all is ok.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is stored in `/data/data/your.package/databases/` You need root access to read `/data`

Example

```
/data/data/com.yourexample.program/databases/
```

Comment: Thank you, problem resolved. The problem was on my program which has no root privileges.